How to create a spectral image from a gas?
Let's say I want to put air through an optical spectrometer.  It doesn't need to be NASA accurate, but suppose I just want a rudimentary measure of carbon from the carbon frequencies.
How can I get "light" from this gas?  Can I just run a high voltage current through it?

The easiest way to get (visible) light from matter is to excite the outer shell electrons, which then emit a photon as they fall back to their ground state. Running a high enough voltage through a gas to create a spark would do just that, and this technique is called spark emission spectroscopy. However, if this is a practical problem you are facing, there are probably easier and more accurate ways to measure the carbon content of air.

I want to measure carbon, hydrogen, and oxygen.  Preferably without altering the gas.  The problem with sparks is that it causes oxidation.  Can you excite a gas without raising the temperature?

You could use a gas discharge tube, but the pressure is very low.
